# Maximal ideal space of $\ell^\infty(A)$, $A$ a commutative unital Banach algbera

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative unital complex Banach algebra with norm $\|\cdot\|_A$, and let $\ell^\infty(A)$ denote all bounded sequences $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n\in A$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$, with pointwise operations and 
the supremum norm:
$$
\|(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\|_{\ell^\infty(A)}=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \|a_n\|_{A}.
$$
Then $\ell^\infty(A)$ is itself a Banach algebra with this norm and pointwise operations. Each element in the product of the maximal ideal space of $\ell^\infty$ with the maximal ideal space of $A$ gives rise to an element of the maximal ideal space of $\ell^\infty(A)$.

Question: Can the maximal ideal space of $\ell^\infty(A)$ ever be bigger than the product of the maximal ideal space of $\ell^\infty$ with the maximal ideal space of $A$?

Comment: What happens if $A=\ell^\infty$?

Comment: Does this show that it is strictly bigger? Can't see it yet... could you give an outline please?

Comment: The maximal ideals of $l^\infty$ correspond to ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$. The algebra $l^\infty(l^\infty)$ is isomorphic to $l^\infty(\mathbb{N}^2)$. Is every ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}^2$ a product of two ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Many thanks for this!